# Python Tkinter sync canvas image loading

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have the following script which creates 2 windows (`Main`, `Image`). The main window contains a button called `Write` and the image window contains a canvas with no image in it. When the `write` button is clicked it moves a "motor" connected to my raspberry pi and then updates the image on the canavas. This process is repeated twice. Unfortunately this is not the case. The motor moves twice before the image is refreshed on the canvas. How do I make it work synchronously?

```
import tkinter as tk                    
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title("Main window")

images = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("1.png")),
            ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("2.png"))]

def move_motor():
    motor.init()
    motor.SetMicroStep('hardward','fullstep')
    motor.TurnStep("forward", steps=50, stepdelay = 1000)
    motor.Stop()

ctr = 0
def update_image():
   global ctr
   ctr += 1
   print(f"Loading: {ctr} image")
   canvas.itemconfig(image_container, image = images[ctr])

# --Problematic function-- #
def write_operations():
    for i in range(1, 3):
        move_motor() # operation 1
        update_image() # operation 2

# image window containing a canvas
imageWin = Toplevel(root)
imageWin.title("Image window")
imageWin.geometry("768x768")
canvas = Canvas(imageWin, width=768, height=768)
image_container = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW, image = None)
canvas.pack()

btn_write = Button(root, text ="Write", command = write_operations).place(x = 130, y = 280)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `move` is most likely a blocking call and interrupts the mainloop. You need to build something that does not block and call it with `after`, as an alternative you can set up a thread and invoking your blocking calls there.

Comment: I also tried `root.after(1000,move_motor())` but it did not make any difference

Comment: The proper way to use after would be `root.after(1000, move_motor)`. Note the lack of `()`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I couldn't get it to work even without `()`

Comment: @BryanOakley Any other thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: @Thingamabobs Any other thoughts or suggestions? –

Comment: Well no, I'm not in the mood to search the docs from a lib I do not use for finding a nonblocking alternative, despite you haven't told us what lib you use. In addition I think there are plenty of tkinter and threading examples out there. You should have enough information to be good to go. You might ask a different question to that other lib. -shrug-

Comment: The simple way is to call `canvas.update_idletasks()` after `canvas.itemconfig(...)` inside `update_image()`.  Note that you will get `IndexError: list index out of range` because you try to show `images[1]` and `images[2]` but the valid index are 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

I simulated your program by putting a slight delay on the motor firing. I replaced the `for` loop with `after`, everything works, if the `after` delay is greater than `sleep` time.

```
import time
from tkinter import *


# root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title("Main window")


def move_motor():
    time.sleep(0.5)


ctr = 0
txt = None


def update_image(fr):
    global ctr, txt
    ctr += 1
    print(f"Loading: {ctr} image")
    if txt:
        canvas.delete(txt)
    txt = canvas.create_text(100, 100, text=ctr, justify=CENTER, font="Verdana 34")
    if ctr == 2:
        root.after_cancel(fr)
        ctr = 0

def write_operations():
    fr = root.after(1000, write_operations)
    move_motor()  # operation 1
    update_image(fr)  # operation 2



# image window containing a canvas
imageWin = Toplevel(root)
imageWin.title("Image window")
imageWin.geometry("768x768")
canvas = Canvas(imageWin, width=768, height=768)
image_container = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=None)
canvas.pack()

btn_write = Button(root, text="Write", command=write_operations).place(x=130, y=280)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The GUI becomes unresponsive for the time it is sleeping.

Comment: @Thingamabobs Yes I know, but if this is some kind of demo program, then this is not a problem.